# Using Mandrill in CakePhp 3 Shell

Tags: shell, cakephp, mandrill

I created a Shell and installed Mandrill over composer

```
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
require_once(ROOT . '/vendor' . DS  . 'Mandrill.php');

/**
 * Mandrill shell command.
 */
class TestShell extends Shell
{
    public function tester(){ 
   $mandrill = new Mandrill('XXXXXX');
    $name = 'XX';


    $template_name = 'test';
    $template_content = array(
        array(),
        array());

    $message = new stdClass();


    $antwortan = "XX";
    $betreff = "XXX " . $name . " ";

    $message->global_merge_vars = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'NACHRICHT',
            'content' => 'test',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'VORNAME',
            'content' => 'XX',
        )
    );
    $blablabla

    }
}
```

But I am getting this error

EDIT:

```
Exception: (Error) - Class 'App\Shell\Mandrill' not found in [/var/www/moving/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 161]
2016-05-24 20:08:37 Error: [Error] Class 'App\Shell\Mandrill' not found
Stack Trace:
#0 [internal function]: App\Shell\TestShell->tester()
#1 /var/www/moving/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(439): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/moving/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(217): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, true, Array)
#3 /var/www/moving/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(181): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->_dispatch(Array)
#4 /var/www/moving/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(127): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->dispatch(Array)
#5 /var/www/moving/bin/cake.php(33): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#6 {main}
```

Sorry If I forgot the code again. More Text so I can add more code.... La La la.... That is annoying and bla bla

My call in the console is:

```
bin/cake test tester
```

Comment: Even though your problems may seem obvious to people who know how CakePHP, PHP (namespaces) and composer works, please don't just post half of the picture, _always_ include the code that actually triggers the error, ie show enough context for people to be able to reproduce the problem!

Comment: Sorry, edited (also for the choose of classname and function)

Comment: The code that causes the error is still missing, it's in your `tester()` method where you are trying to use the `Mandrill` class.

Comment: @ndm okay. I think I got it this time -.-

Comment: I added it to my bootstrap.php - it works, but is this save?

    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . "Mandrill" . DS . "Mandrill.php");